# How to link an array to another array through a common value

Tags: python, arrays, lxml

I'm creating an XML document through a text plain data in Python using lxml, and I'm having problems linking one Array with another array that has one common value. One array is called Promotion and the another is called TotalAmount.

The desire structure in the XML is the following:

```
<Header>
   <Promotion>
       <PromotionData>
           Promotion_1 data
       </PromotionData>
       <TotalAmount>
           Promotion_1 Amount
       </TotalAmount>
   </Promotion>
   <Promotion>
       <PromotionData>
           Promotion_2 data
       </PromotionData>
       <TotalAmount>
           Promotion_2 Amount
       </TotalAmount>
   </Promotion>
</Header>
```

The data that I'm transforming comes distributed like this:

```
4baz                    PROMOTION_1         foo
4baz                    PROMOTION_1         foo
4baz                    PROMOTION_1         foo
4baz                    PROMOTION_2         foo
4baz                    PROMOTION_2         foo
4baz                    PROMOTION_2         foo
```

The digit `4` at the beggining of every line is the ID for this "type of register", and this is the data that I need to put into the `<PromotionData>` tag.

And the data for the tag `<TotalAmount>` comes like this:

```
5PROMOTION_1            bar                 foo
5PROMOTION_2            bar                 foo
```

The digit `5` at the beggining of every line is the ID for this "type of register".

I'm reading this data and separate them into diferents arrays... So I have array_1 and array_2.

What is the best form to link or loop through these arrays using the common value in a way that every `PROMOTION_1` or `PROMOTION_2` connects to its corresponding data and getting an output like in the desire structure?

Comment: Do you care about the type of register?

Comment: Yes but I only use it to separate one type from another and create the arrays.

Comment: Your example is unclear. Is 'foo' is the same as 'foo'. Or 'foo' can be anything. It is the same as 'bar' and 'baz'  How does the first entry "4baz                    PROMOTION_1         foo"  relate to "5PROMOTION_1            bar                 foo"?

Comment: If type of register is not significant at this stage, strip it off and joint two tables together using promotion column. Is this what you want?

Comment: Sorry for that, foo and bar are dummy data, 'foo' can be anything, is the same for 'bar' and 'baz'. The common values are PROMOTION_1 and PROMOTION_2.

Comment: I want to iterate in a way that I get all the ```4baz                    PROMOTION_1         foo``` with the corresponding ```5PROMOTION_1            bar                 foo```. I strip the id from those values. So ignore the 4 and 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from lxml import etree

data1 = [('4baz', 'PROMOTION_1', 1),
         ('4baz', 'PROMOTION_1', 2),
         ('4baz', 'PROMOTION_1', 3),
         ('4baz', 'PROMOTION_2', 4),
         ('4baz', 'PROMOTION_2', 5),
         ('4baz', 'PROMOTION_2', 6)
         ]
data2 = [('5PROMOTION_1', 1, 2), ('5PROMOTION_2', 3, 4)]


root = etree.Element('Header')
for d1 in data1:
    for d2 in data2:
        if d1[1] in d2[0]:
            promotion = etree.Element('Promotion')
            root.append(promotion)
            data = etree.Element('PromotionData')
            data.text = f'{d1[1]} {d1[2]}'
            promotion.append(data)
            data = etree.Element('TotalAmount')
            data.text = f'{d2[1]} {d2[2]}'
            promotion.append(data)

out = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
print(out.decode('utf8'))
```

Output

```
<Header>
  <Promotion>
    <PromotionData>PROMOTION_1 1</PromotionData>
    <TotalAmount>1 2</TotalAmount>
  </Promotion>
  <Promotion>
    <PromotionData>PROMOTION_1 2</PromotionData>
    <TotalAmount>1 2</TotalAmount>
  </Promotion>
  <Promotion>
    <PromotionData>PROMOTION_1 3</PromotionData>
    <TotalAmount>1 2</TotalAmount>
  </Promotion>
  <Promotion>
    <PromotionData>PROMOTION_2 4</PromotionData>
    <TotalAmount>3 4</TotalAmount>
  </Promotion>
  <Promotion>
    <PromotionData>PROMOTION_2 5</PromotionData>
    <TotalAmount>3 4</TotalAmount>
  </Promotion>
  <Promotion>
    <PromotionData>PROMOTION_2 6</PromotionData>
    <TotalAmount>3 4</TotalAmount>
  </Promotion>
</Header>
```